Use graphql to change the "alt" text of the images
i'm currently working for a Shopify store and my supervisor asked to changed all alt texts of the images using graph ql. I have no experience using graph ql and how to achieve this. Can you provide me any guide and some - on how to do this??

You can try fetching product medis first and updating product images with the following documentation https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-04/mutations/productImageUpdate#examples-Update_a_product_s_image
